# MySQL: Single query that only displays rows where id doesn't exist in both tables

Tags: mysql, sql

Given the following two tables, how do I write a single query that only displays the rows that have an `id` that doesn't exist in both tables?

```
table_one
--------------
id    | name
4     | Jack
5     | John
6     | Henry
8     | Frank
9     | Bob
```

```
table_two
--------------
id    | name
4     | Jack
6     | Henry
8     | Frank
```

Output after query is ran: `John Bob`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming you meant "exists in one table or the other table, but not in both tables" - you use subqueries and a union select!

```
    SELECT name FROM table_one WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table_two) 
UNION SELECT name from table_two WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table_one);
```

Also, if you wanted those results to be grouped up for you into a single result row:

```
SELECT group_concat(x.name) FROM 
  (SELECT name FROM table_one 
      WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table_two) 
   UNION SELECT name from table_two 
       WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM table_one)) as x;
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be simple if MySQL had a [FULL OUTER JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_outer_join#Full_outer_join) operator: such a join returns a row for each record in each table, joined on the ID if a record exists on both sides, NULLs on the non-existent side if not. You could then make the same check @ajreal suggests on both sides of the join.

Instead, you could UNION the results of a LEFT and RIGHT JOIN...

```
SELECT table_one.name
FROM table_one
LEFT JOIN table_two ON table_one.id = table_two.id
WHERE table_two.id IS NULL
UNION
SELECT table_two.name
FROM table_one
RIGHT JOIN table_two ON table_one.id = table_two.id
WHERE table_one.id IS NULL
```

Comment: Aside from the desire for equilibrium, anyone care to explain why this was downvoted?